# C Splitting bits

Tags: c, macros

I have a 16 bit address and I need to split this into 15-8 for page number and 7-0 for offset.

So, I am guessing I could do bitwise ops on it?

Let's say `0xBEEF` is address that needs to be split.

Page Number:
`0xBEEF & 0xFF80= 1011 1110 1110 1111 & 1111 1111 1000 0000 = 1011 1110 1000 0000 = 0xBE80`

Offset:
`0xBEEF & 0x007F= 1011 1110 1110 1111 & 0000 0000 0111 1111 = 0000 0000 0110 1111 = 0x006F`

Are there different ways to do this besides bitwise arithmetic in C for macro?

Comment: You can use bitwise struct but in your case bitwise operation you used is good choice

Comment: The usual word is "masked" rather than "split".

Comment: do you realize that you say in your question you want to split bite 15-8 and 7-0, and that your code actually splits bits 15-7 and 6-0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of ways you could do this differently, but I can recommend **none of them**.

splitting a 16 bit value in high and low bits is a very tricky thing to do in C, because the order of the bits depends on the endianness of your hardware. if your system is a big endian system, the high bit will be stored second, and if your system is little endian, the high bit is stored first.

Let's take your example of 0xBEEF, here's what it looks like in memory:

```
little endian     |     big endian
-------------------------------------
... EF BE ...     |     ... BE EF ...
```

if you're using bit arithmetics to separate these two bytes, you don't have to care about their order in memory, but virtually any other method will be affected, requiring you to somehow detect the endianness and program conditionally to have a portable solution.

That being said, here are a couple of alternatives that you could use if you don't care about portability:

**1.) the cast**

this method is basically the one proposed by icepack. you take the adress of the variable, cast it to a pointer to char, and treat it as an array, to get the separate bytes.

**2.) the union**

having the same effect as the cast, you could also create a union like that:

```
union myvalue
  {
    uint16_t value;
    uint8_t bytes[2];
  }
```

to be able to separately adress the bytes and the value

**3.) the reverse**

another completely differently approach would be to store your 16 bit data in an array of unsigned chars in the first place, you're buying calculation overhead on the address, but you don't need to separate the bytes. of course, if the address is somehow the result of a calculation, and you have to split the bytes anyway, this would not make sense anymore.

**a final word - please use AND and shifting to extract the bytes, if you care about the portability of your code.**

Comment: Very comprehensive and well-written!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the bitshift operator in most programs.

`top8 = 0xABCD >> 8;
bottom8 = 0xABCD & 0x00FF;`

This will give you `top8 = 0x00AB` and `bottom8 = 0x00CD`.

Note that you don't have to shift them by 8 bits, it can be anything.

Comment: How does this hold for "*besides bitwise arithmetic*"?

Comment: Bit shifting only involves one variable, and thus is not arithmetic. Arithmetic, by definition, requires a minimum of two principle objects. But I hear what you're saying, it's sort of a grey area.

Comment: You also use operator `&`. But that's not the point - arity and bitwise arithmetics are orthogonal to each other, there is no direct relation between them.

Comment: You are totally right about the `&` operation. But I have always been led to believe that shifting is used because it takes fewer arguments than standard bitwise arithmetic (OR, AND, XOR & NOT). Note that I am talking about logic shifts, not arithmetic shifts.

Comment: Wait, no, I am talking about arithmetic shifts. Logic shifts are the 'get rid of the zeros' one. But I still stand by my definition of arithmetic.

Comment: That's true, but it's still bitwise operation

Comment: I agree, it is just not bitwise arithmetic :)

Comment: It definitely is. This discussion is going nowhere, let's stop

Comment: I agree. I need to remind myself of that more often. Have a one-up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this without bit manipulations:

For big-endian systems:

```
#define OFFSET(x) (*(unsigned char *)x)
#define PAGE(x)   (*((unsigned char *)x + 1))
```

For little-endian systems switch the definitions of `OFFSET` and `PAGE`.

Note the assumption that char is 8 bit in your system (if it's not for some weird reason, use the appropriate 8-bit type).

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin thanks, fixed. BTW this suggestion isn't presumed to be totally portable - 2 portability issues already mentioned but there may well be more.