# How do I split 2 bytes with unsigned char into 5 bits, 5 bits and 6 bits each and allot them different functions?

Tags: c

How can I split 2 bytes into different bits of my choice for something that I have been working on?

Comment: Study the [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

Comment: Have you seen this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319804/c-splitting-bits

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to work with a union:

```
typedef union tagMyType
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned Part1    :5;
        unsigned Part2    :5;
        unsigned Part3    :6;
    };
    struct
    {
        unsigned char  Byte1;
        unsigned char  Byte2;
    };
}MyTypeT;


....
MyTypeT   A;
A.Byte1 = 0x01;    
A.Byte2 = 0x02;
A.Part1 .......  // 5 Bits and so on...
```